# Парсер по идентификатору почты России

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Может кто сталкивался с задачей получения информации о посылке по почтовому идентификатору?

[Ссылка](http://www.russianpost.ru/rp/servise/ru/home/postuslug/trackingpo) на сайте почты России.

Почтовый идентификатор для теста 11773845169145.

Может кто делал парсер или знает, вдруг у почты есть API? На письма они не отвечают, по телефону естественно программисты не сидят у них, так что выбить информацию не получается.

Если у кого есть идеи то рад выслушать.

Comment: По-моему яндекс занимается и такой почтой тоже, напишите им, быть может что то подскажут.

Comment: Ну может и да, может и нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ, и распарсил сайт.